# Voice patch panel wired to outer pair

Tags: telephony, rackmount, pbx, wiring

Our Intertel phone system uses an unusual wiring scheme at the phone by using the outer pair (pins 2 and 5) of wires on a phone jack.

I am looking for anyone that knows of a vendor that sells 24 port patch panels that have 25 pair Amphenol connectors on the back wired to the outer pair of pins on an 8P2C jack on the front.  I don't have any issue finding products wired for the inner pair (pins 3 and 4).

I know I can get adapters such as [this](http://www.sandman.com/wizard.html#ModSwapper) that can swap the pair at either the phone or the jack.  I'd rather avoid that extra expense and mess by having it done properly at the panel itself.

Has anyone seen such a patch panel or know a vendor that can provide one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [BlackBox](http://www.blackbox.com)  I've used them to make custom cables in the past.  If they don't have teh patch panel you need,  I'd expect that they can make them.   Their sales engineers seem to know the products they sell.

Answer (score 0):

You can order a customer panel from many vendors, or buy a punch tool and switch them yourself. 24 ports would take you about 30 mins.

Comment: I'd prefer not to have to dismantle and repunch a panel.  Do you know of one of these "many vendors"?

Comment: Hmm. There are really too many. Blackbox as BillN said will do it.

http://www.google.com/search?btnG=Google+Search&q=custom+patch+panels

I have used Pairmate: 602-431-8129 since they were local to a datacenter I was managing.